# How to hide pry scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

Sometimes when I open a `binding.pry` session in a spec it shows me a too long scope in the shell like the following and takes all the shell line:

```
[3] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Scope::AfterSeed::BehavesLikeAnExportableToExcelModel::WhenImportingFromSpreadsheet::AXlsxFile>)>
```

It turns impossible to use the shell when the level is too deep, and this scope information becomes pointless. How can I hide this scope to something like `pry(#hidden_info>)>` and still have the methods and variables from the previous scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pry prompt can be [configured in a variety of ways](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Customization-and-configuration#Config_prompt). The prompt value can [take any arbitrary form](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Customization-and-configuration#the-prompt-name). (the limit is whatever you can do in Ruby)

You can see the `DEFAULT_PROMPT` values [in the rdocs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/pry/pry/Pry#DEFAULT_PROMPT-constant):

```
[
 proc { |target_self, nest_level, pry|
   "[#{pry.input_array.size}] #{pry.config.prompt_name}(#{Pry.view_clip(target_self)})#{":#{nest_level}" unless nest_level.zero?}> "
 },

 proc { |target_self, nest_level, pry|
   "[#{pry.input_array.size}] #{pry.config.prompt_name}(#{Pry.view_clip(target_self)})#{":#{nest_level}" unless nest_level.zero?}* "
 }
]
```

In your case, you would probably want to put the following into `~/.pryrc` and then restart any pry sessions:

```
Pry.config.prompt = [
 proc { |target_self, nest_level, pry|
   "[#{pry.input_array.size}] #{pry.config.prompt_name}#{":#{nest_level}" unless nest_level.zero?}> "
 },

 proc { |target_self, nest_level, pry|
   "[#{pry.input_array.size}] #{pry.config.prompt_name}#{":#{nest_level}" unless nest_level.zero?}* "
 }
]
```

This removes the `Pry.view_clip(target_self)` call which will clip the class from the prompt.

There are examples [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084481/how-can-i-set-my-pry-prompt-to-be-the-current-timestamp) for configuring the pry prompt as well.

Comment: It Worked, thanks and congrats for the awesome and organized explanation